# How compiler manage return inline function?

Tags: c++, function, compiler-construction, inline

Let say I have an inlined function like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61ed2763e01599c4):

```
inline double CalculateValue() {
    // some condition
    if (true) {
        // some other condition
        if (true) {
            // another condition
            if (true) {
                return 1.0;
            }

            // somethings
            std::cout << "inside1" << std::endl;
        }

        // somethings
        std::cout << "inside2" << std::endl;
    }

    return 2.0;
}

void Process() {
    double value = CalculateValue();

    value *= 100.0;

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Process();
}
```

It will "copy and paste" the `CalculateValue()` function within the `Process()` one. The result is `100`, as expected.

But if I try to [emulate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fec78242ae61a954) how this "copy and paste" will be performed, there's something I don't understand:

```
void Process() {
    double value;

    // some condition
    if (true) {
        // some other condition
        if (true) {
            // another condition
            if (true) {
                value = 1.0;
                return;
            }

            // somethings
            std::cout << "inside1" << std::endl;
        }

        // somethings
        std::cout << "inside2" << std::endl;
    }

    value = 2.0; 

    value *= 100.0;

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Process();
}
```

Of course when it reaches the `return` statement, the rest of the function must be ignored (i.e. `inside1` and `inside2` must never be printed), because of the `return`. But if I `return` from the parent function (`Process()`), it returns immediately, so I can't ever see `100`.

This means it does it another way.

How does the compiler manage this situation? I tried to create a code block, but still the `return` returns to the main function...

Comment: compiler obviously does not use return, I don't know exactly which one is used, but there are plenty other options like `while(1) { ... break; }` or even `goto`'s or some more obscure steps with resulting asm

Comment: `inline` does not change the semantics of a function call, only it's linkage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing your "emulation" you forgot to handle one of the `return`s. In an inlined function the compiler would kind of replace it with a `goto` statement.

```
void Process() {
    double value;

    // begin of inlined function

    // some condition
    if (true) {
        // some other condition
        if (true) {
            // another condition
            if (true) {
                value = 1.0;
                goto next;     // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  return replaced by goto
            }

            // somethings
            std::cout << "inside1" << std::endl;
        }

        // somethings
        std::cout << "inside2" << std::endl;
    }

    value = 2.0; 
 next:   
    //end of inlined function

    value *= 100.0;

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `goto` evil for programming? :)

Comment: What do you think is behind the scene of `if-then-else`? `goto` is not bad *per se* (as a knife), only its usages can be good or bad.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès paizza's comment was probably meant to be ironic.

Comment: I was ironic :) Thank you for clarify this!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the inlined code would treat the `return` more like a `goto`, eg:

```
void Process() {
    double value;

    // some condition
    if (true) {
        // some other condition
        if (true) {
            // another condition
            if (true) {
                value = 1.0;
                goto nextStep;
            }

            // somethings
            std::cout << "inside1" << std::endl;
        }

        // somethings
        std::cout << "inside2" << std::endl;
    }

    value = 2.0; 

nextStep:

    value *= 100.0;

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

The process of inlining is more than just "copy and paste", the resulting code has to make sense within the code it is being injected into.  The compiler is free to modify and optimize the inline code as needed while maintaining the semantics of the original code